# Power over ethernet and common-mode termination

Tags: inductor, ethernet, termination, twisted-pair

I have a non-standard Power over Ethernet application (connector, and devices are not ethernet standard but we are using ethernet pairs and protocol for communications). On looking at PoE schematics I have noticed that none of them incorporate common mode termination in the design. Isn't common mode termination needed at all, or does the PoE standard reduces maximum cable runs to compensate?

I was planning to use the following circuit for termination (with its equivalent on the ground side, values are estimates), is this overkill?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvRXA1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which schematics you have looked at, but many I have looked at do include termination.  POE doesn't really change things in that regard.

See this question:

[Bob Smith Termination with POE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134618/bob-smith-termination-with-poe)

Also:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua454/slua454.pdf

Comment: I guess I had been looking at "simplified" and conceptual schematics in the data sheets. They just show diodes connecting directly to the magnetics. Even in some actual schematics of PoE injectors they just allow the common mode to pass through!! (rather silly if you ask me). So they have no termination whatsoever.